# PrintDocument HasMorePages doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, printing

A datatable (dt) contains the data I want to print. 15 rows can fit on one page. The code works well for the first page, but the commented lines do not work, and an infinite number of pages are printed. Can anyone help fix this?

```
private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    for (int y = 0; y <= dt.Columns.Count; y++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 50 + (y * 150), 150, 50 + (y * 150), 1000);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 50, 200 + (x * 50), 700, 200 + (x * 50));
    }

    for (int z = 0; z < dt.Rows.Count; z++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < dt.Columns.Count; d++)
        {
            string element = dt.Rows[z][d].ToString();
            e.Graphics.DrawString(element, new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, 60 + (d * 150), 210 + (50 * Rows));
        }
        //if (z % 15 == 0)
        //{ e.HasMorePages = true; Rows = 0; break; }
        //else { e.HasMorePages = false; }
        Rows++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by the commented lines "don't work"? Do you mean e.HasMorePages always returns true?

Comment: No, I mean that hasmorepages returns infinite pages ..and the 1st page returns the data of 1st row only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an infinite number of pages print, your problem has to do with how you are determining if `e.HasMorePages` = `true`. Since `z` starts at `0`, it can never get past `15` because once it gets to `15`, the loop breaks and `e.HasMorePages = true`, and `z` = `0` again. What you could do to fix your problem is have a variable that keeps track of how many pages you have printed. You could try something like this:

```
int pages = 0;
private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
//...

    for (int z = pages * 15; z < dt.Rows.Count; z++)
    {
       for (int d = 0; d < dt.Columns.Count; d++)
         {
             //draw text
         }
       if (z - pages * 15 == 15)
       { e.HasMorePages = true; Rows = 0; pages++; break; }
       else { e.HasMorePages = false; }
       Rows++;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Make sure that you reset `pages` back to zero every time you start to print, or else it won't print correctly. You could use the `BeginPrint` event.

```
private void Doc_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) 
{
    pages = 0;
}
```

Comment: it still returns infinite pages

Comment: Did you make sure to put this in `pages++`?

Comment: Could you post the updated code, or at least the parts of the code you changed?

Comment: int pages = 0;
            for (int z = (pages*15); z < dt.Rows.Count; z++)
            {
               for (int d = 0; d < dt.Columns.Count; d++)
                 {
                     string element = dt.Rows[z][d].ToString();
                     e.Graphics.DrawString(element, new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, 60 + (d * 150), 210 + (50 * Rows));
                 }
               if ((z-(pages*15)) == 15)
               { e.HasMorePages = true; Rows = 0; pages++; break; }
               else { e.HasMorePages = false; }
               Rows++;
            }

Comment: I'm sorry for its appearance like this, and I'm thankful in advance for any help.

Comment: `pages` has to be declared outside the void. idk if you did that

Comment: No problem. Since it answered your question, do you think you could mark it as so? This will help other users who have the same problem as you.

Comment: You need to document that the BeginPrint event is also needed.  It must set the *pages* variable back to 0.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for pointing that out. I added that to the post.